# QuickFix.Net.NetCore Nuget Package: How to generate fields from custom dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, quickfix, quickfixn

I would like to use the following nuget packages, which looks like a fork of the original .net QuickFix packages/codebase provided by Connamara Systems.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/QuickFix.Net.NETCore/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/QuickFix.Net.NETCore.FIX43/

I have to use a custom dictionary. When using the source code, there is this `generate.rb` ruby script that can be used.

**But how does this field generation work when installing via Nuget?**

Comment: This sounds very library specific - nothing wrong with that, but: the question you're asking isn't obvious (in particular: there's no code, and it isn't clear whether you're asking about dictionaries, vs asking about `generate.rb`); have you tried the "issues" tab on the repo? https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/issues

Comment: Thx for replying. When looking at this (`https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/tree/master/generator`) folder within the original repo, we have to use the aforementioned `generate.rb` to generate the custom messages. But when we are using the nuget package there is no such script. So how can we generate messages based on a custom dictionary?